# Testing for similarity between countries

Tags: anova, t-test, spss

For my thesis, I am looking at the effect of environmental controversies on the profitability of Chinese and European firms. As part of my exploratory analysis, I have to check whether or not the European countries are similar enough to consider them as 1 group.

I collected data on economic development and cultural dimensions. However, I am unsure which test I can use to check for similarity between the countries. The data looks as follows:

[image]

The end goal would be to have a test confirming that the European countries are similar enough to consider as 1 group, and to have a test confirming that the European group is significantly different from China.

If anyone has any idea on which tests I can use for this, please let me know! All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the China and Europa comparison, I think you can try clustering. By showing that two clustering groups give the optimal evaluation criteria, You can say they belong to different groups to some degree. Although I had to say it's not as solid as having a statistical test and obtaining a P-value that is very small. 
Another way is to try F-test, ANOVA. Transpose your table, you will get something like a stratified designed experiment with each level has only one experiment record which is the value in the cell. And you want the null prosthesis to be Au=Be=Fra=Ger.....(Except China) Then you can do another with China in it.